# Supplying Solar Shower

Tags: water

I want to use a sump pump to deliver water to a 50 gallon plastic drum that's 15' high. The 1 HP pump has a 1 1/4" outlet and I want to reduce it to 3/4" hose for convenience and storage. The drum is 150' from the lake. Will this work?

Comment: What's the nameplate on the pump?

Comment: Yes, and we also need to know the elevation difference between the surface of the lake and the base of the tank.  If the tank is up a hill, that matters.

Answer (score 1):

All pumps will pump to a specified head or height that is listed in feet.  If you exceed the allowed head then the pump will not pump. The head is the combined height in feet from the pumps discharge + the resistance of the supply piping.If the total resistance is above the pumps capacity then this will not work and you will have to utilize either a different pump or a series of pumps.You could use a "sump pump" and an inline pump or some other combination to give you the required Head.